# django 1.10 postgres full text search is not working

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, full-text-search

I am trying to integrate full text search for django 1.10 with postgres database.
I am following tutorial from 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/search/

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    ans = models.TextField(max_length=1500, blank=True)
```

I have several questions in the database which has the text 'for' in its text field for example: one question is:

```
text: what is best for me?
ans: this is best for you.
```

I am trying to make a query like

```
q = Question.objects.filter(text__search='for')
```

But this query is not returning any result. can anyone suggest me why?

Comment: To use the search lookup, 'django.contrib.postgres' must be in your INSTALLED_APPS. Did you put it there

Comment: (1) Check what query is actually being run by turning statement logs on in PostgreSQL and checking the logs.
(2) Make sure "for" isn't a stop-word with your dictionary and filtered out.

Comment: I added 'django.contrib.postgres'  in postgres. It's not only for 'for' word. If i replace for with other word like 'the' then it also not showing correct results.
2) my query:
 
SELECT ••• FROM "faq_question" WHERE to_tsvector(COALESCE("faq_question"."text", '')) @@ (plainto_tsquery('for')) = true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually my mistake. For Full text search when Postgres creates index it by default ignore common words like 'the', 'for', 'are','is' etc. So If you try to search using this keywords you search query will return empty even if there are lots of sentences with these words.
I did not know this. So I thought I misconfigured.